# Check if duplicate exist with a condition

Tags: c#, sql

I have a datatable which is populated from my database. I have a function to add and update data but now I would like to check whether data exist or not. But I have to check two things

If data exist in database check whether it is enabled or disabled, if enabled then then should return message="Data exist in the table" else "Data is disabled."

```
    bool nameExists;

        connection statement
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText =
                @"SELECT TOP 1 0 " +
                @"FROM [dbo].[products] p WITH (NOLOCK) " +
                @"WHERE [p].[name] = @name";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", name);
            command.CommandTimeout = 100;
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                nameExists = reader.HasRows;
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
```

How do I enhance my query to check above conditions?

**Note** Please don't degrade this post instead post a comment if you think this post is not a good post. Also forgive me for my grammatical mistakes if exist in my post.

Comment: IF NOT EXISTS exists within SQL - Try looking into that.

Comment: @MethodMan that is not a typo. Previously I was checking it without condition now I would like to have a condition with it

Comment: Could you give more information? what data type is "enabled" , what is the name of the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a column named `Enabled` that is an `int` datatype, and `0` represents disabled and `1` represents enabled, then this might do what you want:

```
declare @Enabled int;
set @Enabled = (
  select top 1
    p.Enabled 
  from dbo.products p with (nolock)
  where p.name = @name
  );

select 
    msg = convert(varchar(32), case 
      when @Enabled is null 
        then 'Data does not exist'
      when @Enabled = 0
        then 'Data is disabled'
      when @Enabled = 1
        then 'Data exist in the table'
    end);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx). It always returns the first column of the first row or `null` if no rows are returned.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string sql = "SELECT enabled FROM dbo.products WITH(nolock) WHERE name = @name";
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection)) {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", name);
        command.CommandTimeout = 100;
        connection.Open();
        object enabled = command.ExecuteScalar();
        if (enabled == null) {
            ... // Product does not exist.
        } else if ((int)enabled == 0) {
            ... // Product is disabled.
        } else {
            ... // Product is enabled.
        }
    }
}
```

Also the using statements automatically close and dispose connnections and commands.

Comment: Name enabled in `Select enabled` and `object enabled` should be same?

Comment: I might have to add `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("enabled", isEnabled);` <-- example right?

Comment: No. You want to know, what the value of `dbo.products.enabled` is for different products. In order to do it, you will call this command with different product names. Therefore, you have the command parameter `@name`. This is the only parameter and it is a **in** parameter. The column `enabled`, however, is a column of the result set (because of `SELECT enabled`). `ExecuteScalar` returns this value as an `object`. It can be assigned to an object variable of any desired name. `null` is returned if no product was found and an `int` having the value of the column `enabled` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can change like following:

```
        bool nameExists;

        connection statement
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText =
                @"SELECT TOP 1 Enabled " +
                @"FROM [dbo].[products] p WITH (NOLOCK) " +
                @"WHERE [p].[name] = @name";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", name);
            command.CommandTimeout = 100;
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                nameExists = reader.HasRows;

                if (nameExists)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    //bool Enabled = (reader.GetInt32(0) == 1);
                    bool Enabled = reader.GetBooean(0);
                    if (Enabled)
                        return "Data exist in the table";
                    else
                        return "Data is disabled.";
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception ("Data not exist in the table");
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: `bool Enabled = (reader.GetInt32(0) == 1);`  Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: @sms1707 Maybe your Enabled column data type is not int.

Comment: Yes you are right it is in bit. Is there any solution using with bit?

Comment: Yes, it is more simple. Just use bool Enabled = reader.GetBoolean(0); I also edited post.